# What kind of connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm building a small PCB project and I need to connect to a third-party accessory that uses the connector pictured below. I've sifted through supplier catalogs looking for it, but without knowing what it's called or what category to search under or anything, I've come up empty.

If anybody has worked on remote car starters before, it's the same connector that Directed Electronics uses for the D2D interface. I can take a few measurements if you guys need.

Edit: The dimensions as close as I can get them are 10.5mm wide x 4 mm tall x 7 mm long. The pitch is 2.5mm, and the distance between the two 'locks' on top is 6mm. The wires are 24AWG.

[image: connector]

[image][image][image]

Comment: The most important measurement is probably the pitch, the distance between each pin (the center of each pin).

Comment: The problem with "ID this connector" questions is that there are many, many very similar connectors on the market. It can be very difficult to tell them apart from one photo.  To help, you can 1) measure the pitch (measure several pins and divide to be accurate), 2) measure the outside dimensions 3) look closely for mould marks or logos and 4) give lots of close-up photos, especially of the latching mechanism.

Comment: Other things you could add to the question.  (1) Gauge of the wires (AWG).  It's usually written along on the wires in small black print.  (2) Photo of the corresponding jack which this plugs into.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added some of that information. It's tough to get in focus pictures and accurate measurements of it cause it's so small, but hopefully we can figure this out. :)

Answer (score 4):

That's a [XH connector](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277) manufactured by JST (but available as clones from almost anywhere).

[image: XH YO]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Managed to find the datasheet for it. Cheers. :)